# When there is a 6 month Gap Grab everything after if there is no 6 month gap then grab everything sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query pull and I need some help.

I am trying to figure out a case when statement when there is a 6 month gap then grab the next number when There is no 6 month gap then grab all of them.

**Example 1**:

```
ID Gap 
1   0
2   4
3   1
4   8
5   1
6   6
7   1
```

So in this example, there is a gap of 8 so if that was the only gap >= 6 then I would just grab that one but since there is another gap of 6 I just want to grab ID 7.

**Example 2:**

```
ID  Gap 
1   0
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    0
```

So in this example, there is no gap. so I want to grab all of those IDs.

This is all in sql

[image]

Comment: Should be good with a CURSOR

Comment: *"...only gap >= 6 then I would just grab that one..."*: can you be explicit at what you would return in that case? From the question's title it would mean returning 5, 6 and 7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use window functions:

```
select id, gap
from (select t.*,
             max(case when gap >= 6 then id end) over (order by id) as id_6
      from t
     ) t
where id > id_6 or id_6 is null;
```

Comment: I have added a picture to the top. So I have tried both and they are not working. The ones highlighted in Yellow are the ones that I need and the ones that have a red strike through them are the ones I don't want. Currently, the results in the screenshot are from the above query.  The cursor is not working properly.

Comment: @khuffman . . . The data in your picture is nothing like the data in the question you presented.  I stand by this answer to your original question.

Comment: Then how would you answer from the picture?

Comment: @khuffman . . . If you have a new question, ask it as a new question.  Your original question was answered twice -- and changing the question would invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

With cursor, didn't test on SSMS. It's another way to do it, not the best but that was for my personal training.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Gap >= 6)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id AS INT;
    DECLARE @gap AS INT;
    DECLARE @id2 AS INT;
    DECLARE @gap2 AS INT;

    DECLARE gap_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        SELECT ID, Gap
        FROM table;

    OPEN gap_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM gap_cursor INTO @id, @gap;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN 
        IF (@gap >= 6)
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM gap_cursor   
            INTO @id, @gap;
            SET @id2 = @id;
            SET @gap2 = @gap;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM gap_cursor INTO @id, @gap;
        END
    END
    SELECT @id2, @gap2;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table;
END
```